# Django can't find my template and look for a specific file name that don't exist

Tags: python, django

I have a `templates` folder inside the folder `core` (my app), with a single file named `home.html`. But I'm getting the following error message in my browser:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /

core/post_list.html

Request Method:   GET
Request URL:   http://localhost:8000/
Django Version:   3.0.8
Exception Type:   TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:   

core/post_list.html

Exception Location:   /home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Virtual_Enviroment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in select_template, line 47
Python Executable:   /home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Virtual_Enviroment/bin/python
Python Version:   3.8.2
Python Path:   

['/home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Django/python-studies/first_django_project',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Virtual_Enviroment/lib/python3.8/site-packages']

Server time:   Sun, 19 Jul 2020 03:31:58 +0000
```

But the thing that caught my eyes is this part:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Virtual_Enviroment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/core/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Virtual_Enviroment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/core/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
    django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/shaiene-kun/Programação/Python/Django/python-studies/first_django_project/core/templates/core/post_list.html (Source does not exist)
```

I don't have no folder `core` inside my `templates` folder and I don't have a `post_list.html` file and nor do I create a reference for this file or path file nowhere in my code so why is it trying to find this? On the other hand I see no mention of the `home.html` file witch is the one I want to render.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':[],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

# Class views
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template = "home.html"

# Create your views here.

# Function Views
# def home(request):
#     return render(request,'home.html', {})
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views
from .views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name="home" ) 
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name = "home"),

]
```

**file system**

```
├── core
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── pycache
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-38.pyc
│   │       └── init.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── pycache
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── home.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── first_django
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── pycache
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

**urls.py in first_django folder**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('core.urls') ) 
]
```

I already tried adding the `template` folder in the DIRS on the `settings.py` file writing the path manually and using `os.path.join` but It didnt work. I tried creating the damm core folder and changing the file to `post_list.html` and well, it worked, but that's not a proper solution :/

**Edit:** I figured it out thanks to Javix70! I changed the attribute `template` to `template_name` in `views.py` and its working fine.

Comment: What is core under your installed apps? Is core the name of your app? If so it should be 'core.apps.CoreConfig'

Comment: yes it is, I changed but still getting the same error

Comment: you need to create a templates folder inside your app and than add all the html inside it. this way django understand where the templates are

Comment: I did this. I added the file system now so you can see it

Comment: What does your urls.py file look like for your first_django? Does it "include" your apps urls.py? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs

Comment: yes I think so, I added the file to the to the question

Comment: If Javix70's answer is correct then please make sure to accept his answer. There should be a checkmark next to his answer.

Answer (score 0):

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views
from .views import HomeView

app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name="home" ) 
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name = "home"),

]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

# Class views
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "home.html"
```

Is template_name =

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: change template for template_name

Comment: ok so I changed the template_name and still nothing, but then I changed the core:home to the actual name of the file and it worked! It recognized the correct path. So well, thank you in a way ^^